# Calculus and perturbing expectation values

Tags: mathematics

Consider the following quantity:
$$
f_O(|\psi\rangle) = \langle \psi | O | \psi \rangle
$$

How would we study a perturbation on $|\psi\rangle$, given that it has to be a valid quantum state? What mathematical tools underlie this quantity?

For example, we might be interested in understanding whether there are specific $|\psi\rangle$ with high sensitivity to disruption.

Comment: you want to preserve normalization, thus a perturbation $\delta\psi$ needs to satisfy $\langle\delta\psi|\psi\rangle=0$. For the expval you just get, assuming Hermitianity, $2\langle\delta\psi|O|\psi\rangle$, so eg eigenstates of $O$ are "insensitive to perturbations" in the first order. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @glS why is it that a perturbation must satisfy orthogonality? Also, I believe I'd be interested more in the sensitivity of f_O given inputs |\psi> vs |\psi'>

Comment: because you need to preserve the normalisation $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$. It's like saying that tangent vectors in a hypersphere attached to $v$ are orthogonal to $v$. I don't really understand the other question. You defined $f_O$ as having a single input. What do you mean with sensitivity "given inputs $|\psi\rangle$ vs $|\psi'\rangle$"?